# Symfony2 : Auto htmlentities using Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, html-entities

I'm displaying some variable retrieved in my database using Twig :

```
<p>{{ my_variable }}</p>
```

The thing is this variable may contain html tags, such as "`<br />`".

Twig seems to automatically call some htmlentities-like function when displaying variables.

Is there any way to disable it so that when I display a variable containing "`Hello<br />world !`" I get :

```
Hello 
world !
```

rather than :

```
Hello<br />world !
```

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `{{ my_variable|raw }}` to prevent `my_variable` from being automatically escaped.

See Twig documentation: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

Comment: Just what I needed, Google didn't give me that filter... or maybe I just didn't make the good search ;) Thanks anyway (I accept in 10 minutes)

Comment: wow, I've recently fallen in love with Symfony2 and its because of things like this. Very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this

```
{% autoescape false %}{{ my_variable}}{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: helped me for the variables containing html entities

Answer (score 1):

even better: `{{ '<br />|raw('html') }}` to avoid unescaping other sensible stuff.

Comment: `html` look like to be the default strategy of `raw`: https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extension/Escaper.php Can you provide some documentation or examples of this usage?

Comment: you can also pass `js` for example, or any callable.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use linebreaks in the text stored in your database but don't care to use html , you can also use the  nl2br filter as in `{{ var|nl2br }}`. Allows you to use string linebreak character `\n` in your text. Filter converts it to `<br/>`